# How can I type an ascii code 127 on MacOS?

Tags: macos, ascii

How can I send ascii code 127(DEL) to a command line utility?
If I just type the key DEL, it will erase the last character instead of putting a character with ascii code 0x7f there. Is there a way to type DEL in ascii code?

I know one approach: put the character in a file and use redirect "<". But can I type this character directly?

Comment: Do you expect some kind of symbol to appear? delete has an ascii code but emitting it does cause an erase. What do you hope to see/get?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the Delete key does actually send ASCII DEL (code 127), but in many contexts it's interpreted as "delete the last character" rather than as a literal part of input to whatever's reading from the terminal. In the specific case of a bash command line, the default readline binding for DEL is the `backward-delete-char` function, so that's what typing it does.

There are a couple of ways to include a literal DEL character in a bash command line. One method is to type Control-V and then Delete. Control-V is (by default) bound to the `quoted-insert` function, which inserts the next character literally in the command line (ignoring any readline function it might normally be bound to). You can use the same Control-V trick to include other characters that normally have special functions, like Escape.

Another method is to use an ANSI-C-escaped string `$'\c?'` as part or all of an argument:

```
printf $'\c?' | xxd -p     # Prints "1f", the hex code for DEL
printf $'X\c?Y' | xxd -p   # Prints "581f59", the hex codes for X, DEL, Y
printf X$'\c?'Y | xxd -p   # Prints the same thing
```